# Adding boolean variable to a function that processes an Observable stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function that takes a parameter ID of a thread. It processes the thread flow to find out if this ID matches a thread.

```
getThreadFromSubscription(threadId: string): Observable<Thread> {
return this.threads
  .filter((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    return Object.keys(threadDictionary).some((key) =>
      threadDictionary[key].id === threadId);
  })
  .map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    for (let key in threadDictionary) {
      if (threadDictionary[key].id === threadId)
      {
        return threadDictionary[key];
      }
    }
  }).first();
}
```

Then, I enroll you to this feed to know the corresponding thread if it exists. If it exists, I add the newMessage to this thread :

```
this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
    .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
      console.log("id: tRev");

      if(thread!== undefined) {
        objMessage.thread = thread;
      }
      objMessage.date = moment().toDate();

      const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);

      thread.messages = Observable.of([newMessage]);

      thread.messages.last().subscribe((message) => {
        [thread.lastMessage] = message;
      });

      this.addMessage(newMessage);
    });
```

I would like to add a boolean variable to this function in order to know if the corresponding thread exists.
The 'newThread' variable will be true if the corresponding thread does not exist.
I tried this, but when the threadID does not exist, it does not work. My boolean variable 'newThread' does not set to true :

```
addNewMessage(objMessage: any) : void {
this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
  .subscribe((thread: Thread) => {
    if(thread !== undefined) {
      this.newThread = false;
    }
    else {
      this.newThread = true;
    }
  });

if(this.newThread === false )
{
  this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
    .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
      console.log("id: tRev");

      if(thread!== undefined) {
        objMessage.thread = thread;
      }
      objMessage.date = moment().toDate();

      const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);

      thread.messages = Observable.of([newMessage]);

      thread.messages.last().subscribe((message) => {
        [thread.lastMessage] = message;
      });

      this.addMessage(newMessage);
    });
}
else
{
  console.log("id: flo");
  const flo: User      = new User(objMessage.author, objMessage.site);
  const newThread: Thread = new Thread(objMessage.id, [flo]);
  const newMessage = new Message(objMessage);

  objMessage.date = moment().toDate();

  newThread.messages = Observable.of([newMessage]);

  newThread.messages.last().subscribe((message) => {
    [newThread.lastMessage] = message;
  });

  objMessage.thread = newThread;

  this.addMessage(newMessage);
  this.addThread(newThread);
}
}
```

Do you know how to add a variable that would tell if the given id is already existing or not?